# Django ListView __init__ accepting keyword arguments

Tags: python, django, listview

I've written this Django ListView (am not very familiar with it), where I tried to override a variable based on slug input using **init**. Somehow it seems like the **init** function has no acces to the keyword arguments. The dispatch function does the job just fine, still I'd like to know why **init** doesn't work. Any ideas?

Code:

Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
form models import MyModel

class MyListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'index.html'

    # does not work
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        return super(MyListView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # works
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print self.kwargs
        return super(MyListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # filter for data based on category_slug input

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        return context
```

Urls.py:

```
url(r'^browse/(?P<category_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)', MyListView.as_view(), name='browse-category'),
```

Answer (score 2):

Because they are *class-based*, you have access to the keyword arguements anywhere in the class via `self`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # filter for data based on category_slug input
    categories = self.model.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'])
    ...
    return categories
```

Comment: Sorry I should probably have explained the question a bit better. I'm aware of this, still I get a `AttributeError: 'MyListView' object has no attribute 'kwargs'` when calling `self.kwargs`?